# How to find out the probability of an event about which we have two informations

Tags: probability, combinatorics, combinations

I would like to know how to find out the probability of an event about which we have two informations. Say we have $A$ and we know it is lower than $K$ but greater than $X$. How do you find the result for any $K$ and $X$ ?

A is a positive random integer uniformly distributed on its range such that:
$A\in\Bbb N$
$A\in\left[0,100\right]$

K is an integer such that:
$K\in\Bbb Z$

X is a number such that:
$X\in\Bbb R$

$P\left\{\left(A< K\right)\wedge\left(A>X\right)\right\}$

How do I figure out P ? Is the following correct ? It does seem so but I get wrong results when I apply this probability.

$$P=\frac{K+ \lfloor X\rfloor+1-101}{101}$$

Where $\lfloor X\rfloor+1$ truncates X and adds one: It's supposed to turn $X$ into an integer without losing accuracy but maybe this step is unnecessary. If so, is the formula correct with that bit simply replaced with $X$?

Comment: If "we know that $A$ is lower than $K$ but greater than $X$", then $P((A<K)\wedge(A>X))=1$.

Comment: Only if $K>100$ and $X<0$. $A$ can then and only then take any value within its range $\left[0, 100\right]$, which is necessary for $P$ to be $1$. Maybe I asked the question in a tricky way, not sure how to reword it though.

Comment: when you say "A is positive random integer" you mean that A is uniformly distributed on $[0,100]$?

Comment: Yes, sorry! Edited.

Comment: $P\left\{\left(A< K\right)\wedge\left(A>X\right)\right\}$ should _decrease_ when $X$ increases, so adding $\lfloor X \rfloor$ (or adding $X$) to $K$ is definitely not right. The good, detailed answer by user190080 shows that you should subtract instead.

Comment: Indeed, I actually adapted my result wrongly after I simplified a bunch of things to make the question clearer. Result should have been:$$P=\frac{K+\left[ 101-\left(\lfloor X\rfloor +1\right)\right] -101}{101}$$ I noticed much later, when trying to understand user190080's answer, that I actually got it right. The wrong results when this probability was applied were due to me badly constraining $X$ and $K$. See my comments to user190080 for more details. Answers from people on StackExchange are amazingly worthwhile, I can't believe I didn't use it until now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First we get 
$$
P\left\{\left(A< K\right)\wedge\left(A>X\right)\right\}=P\left\{X<A<K\right\}
$$
which gives us, since $A$ is uniformly distributed on $[0,100]$, the following
$$
P\left\{X<A<K\right\}=(P\left\{A<K\right\}-P\left\{A \leq X\right\})*1_{X<K}
$$
with
$$
P\left\{A<K\right\}=\begin{cases}\frac{K}{101}\quad\quad 0\leq K \leq101\\ 1 \quad \quad K\ge 101 \\0 \quad\quad \text{otherwise} \end{cases}
$$
and 
$$
P\left\{A \leq X\right\}=\begin{cases}\frac{ \lfloor X \rfloor +1}{101} \quad \quad X\in[0,100]\\1 \quad \quad X\ge100\\0 \quad \quad \text{otherwise} \end{cases}
$$
which gives us finally for $X,K\in[0,101]$ and $X<K$
$$
P\left\{X<A<K\right\}=\frac{K-\lfloor X \rfloor -1}{101}
$$

bests

Comment: Thanks! I ended up with a similar result but it was tedious. Is your "$\times 1_{X<K}$" notation to indicate that $P\{X<A<K\}$ is only true for $X<K$, which means there is also a "$\times 0_{X\ge K}$" that can be omitted ? Anyway, to get the result to work regardless of relationship between $K$ and $X$ I $clamp$ed them individually in $\left[0,101\right]$ as well as their sum: $$P=\frac{ clamp\left[ clamp\left(K\right)-clamp\left(\lfloor X \rfloor\right) -1\right]}{101}$$ Is it exact, or just very accurate ? I'm not sure, but at least I can use the formula because it is good enough.

Comment: @James yes, the $1_{X<K} $ was to indicate that this is only true for $X<K$, since that was the assumption. All the other possibilities get probability 0. What do you mean by "clamped"?

Comment: $clamp\left( X,0,101\right)$ means that X is constrained within $\left[0, 101\right]$. If $X<0$ then the result of the clamp is $0$, and if $X>101$ then the result of the clamp is $101$. Otherwise it is just $X$. It's shorthand for $$\max\left[ 0,\min\left( X,101\right) \right]$$ I used clamp because this formula represents the odds for a certain conditional branch to trigger in a program, and in that program the relationship between $X$ and $K$ isn't set in stone.

Comment: @James so yes, basically you can adapt your result, if you don't know the relation of X and K before. I thought you are giving these boundaries yourself. Just for the sake of it you could simply write down the second case where you want to compute $P(K<A<X)$. The problem is if you want to compute  $P(K<A<X)$ while using $P=\frac{ clamp\left[ clamp\left(K\right)-clamp\left(\lfloor X \rfloor\right) -1\right]}{101}$ you get a positive probability of the event $ K<A<X$ for $K=10,X=2$ although it should be $0$. so be careful with your clamps :)

Comment: That's a great point so I went ahead and tested the actual result from the program that our formula is attempting to describe. The program uses conditional branches and the particular one that we are interested in is hard coded in such a way that it can only be true when $A<K$ AND $A>X$. I recorded the amount of times it is true out of $50000$ attempts when $K=10$ and $X=2$, and it appears that it was not $0$ but exactly what our formula using clamps predicted: $\frac{7}{101}$. I don't quite get it. I don't see any mistake in my interpretation of the conditions, it's not that complex anyway.

Comment: @James if you get a result which is close to $\frac{7}{101}$ while using the bounds $K=10$ and $X=2$, then you did everything all right, since this exactly the case of  $P\left\{X<A<K\right\}=\frac{K-\lfloor X \rfloor -1}{101}$. What I was pointing on is, that if you switch the roles of X and K, then you have obviously to adapt the above formula...sorry if wasn't clear enough!

Comment: Ah no, it's my bad! My confusion was based on the fact that I considered the wrong proposition. Indeed there's nothing surprising in getting a result above $0$ when $K=10$ and $X=2$, if the proposition is $P\left\{ X<A<K\right\}$. And if I take $K=2$ and $X=10$, then indeed the program never validates the conditional branch we are interested in. So everything is as expected. Thanks again for all your help!

Comment: @James Glad that it works!