# How to reduce the standard deviation from $P$ where $P$ involves a random integer uniformly distributed in $\left[ 0,100\right]$

Tags: probability, standard-deviation, uniform-distribution

I have a probability $P$ derived from:
- A random integer $A$ uniformly distributed on its range such that $A\in\left[0, 100\right]$
- An integer $K$ such that $K\in\Bbb N$
- A number $X$ such that $X\in\Bbb R$
- The relationship between $X$ and $K$ is unknown

$$P\left\{\left( A<K\right)\wedge\left( A>X\right)\right\}=P\left\{X<A<K\right\}=\frac{clamp\left[ clamp\left(K\right) -clamp\left(\lfloor X \rfloor\right) -1\right]}{101}$$

Where $clamp\left( X\right)$ is shorthand for $\max\left[ 0,\min\left( X,101\right)\right]$, i.e. $X$ is constrained within $\left[0, 101\right]$.

To learn more about $P$ and its result, you can read my [previous question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1343509/how-to-find-out-the-probability-of-an-event-about-which-we-have-two-informations). $P$ represents a conditional branch in a program and the result is supposed to predict how often this branch will be true.

**Preliminary question:** I would now like to calculate the standard deviation for that probability. How do I do that ? I know it is the square root of the variance, but I'm not sure how to get variance in the first place.

**Bulk of the question:** Because standard deviation is going to be large considering the range of $A$ and the low amount of attempts, I will most likely want to reduce it. How should I do that ? Is it even possible to reduce the standard deviation when you deal with a uniformly distributed random number ?

The goal in the end is to provide a result for $P$ that will have a low standard deviation so that it should be reliable even with only $10$-$15$ rolls of this $101$-faced dice to which the constraints detailed earlier are applied. (The average of these $10$-$15$ attempts should always be very close to $P$, for any batch of $10$-$15$ attempts)

I get the feeling that standard deviation cannot be reduced without modifying the program, which sounds like it would defeat the purpose of using $P$ to describe it.

Comment: What do you mean by std of that probability? It's a number... Probably, $X$ and $K$ are also random so that you probability is actually $P\{X<A<K|X,K\}$. If this is the case then you need to characterize $X$ and $K$...

Comment: $X$ and $K$ are known before calculation. They are not random, but they are program variables so they can take any value.
I'm pretty bad with statistics as you can see so I'll explain differently. Since the conditional branch depends on $A$ and $A$ is random with quite a wide range, a single run through the branch may be very far from the result of $P$. That result becomes more and more accurate as you run through the branch while counting how many times it is true versus how many runs occurred.

Comment: At say $15$ runs, unless I am completely wrong on vocabulary, you'll still have a large standard deviation since variance is itself likely to be very large. My question is first, how can I figure out variance (and thus standard deviation), and then how, if at all possible, I can alter the results gotten from $15$ runs through the conditional branch so that standard deviation is low and my prediction represented by the result of $P$ is reliable. I hope it's clear enough.

Comment: OK. So, you estimate $P$ by running the program several times and measuring the relative number of "successes" ($X<A<K$)?

Comment: I defined $P$ and then calculated it with a formula separately from the program. The formula is attempting to describe reality, so I do compare it to results obtained through the means you described, but ultimately I don't want to run the program several times. I want the formula to accurately describe reality and that means people experiencing that reality by running through that conditional branch $15$ times should be able to average their successes and get a result pretty close to the result that my formula predicted separately.

Comment: Sorry that I'm not very clear. It's possible that what I want is impossible. Still, I'm curious about how to calculate variance in our case, just to be able to measure accuracy of my formula and inform people about it based on the number of runs. That would be good enough already, in the event that standard deviation can't be reduced in my situation.